# Neighbors in the matrix - algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a problem with coming up with an algorithm for the "graph" :(
Maybe one of you would be so kind and direct me somehow <3

The task is as follows:
We have a board of at least 3x3 (it doesn't have to be a square, it can be 4x5 for example). The user specifies a sequence of moves (as in Android lock pattern). The task is to check how many points he has given are adjacent to each other horizontally or vertically.

Here is an example:
Matrix:

- 1 2 3 4
- 5 6 7 8
- 9 10 11 12

The user entered the code: 10,6,7,3
The algorithm should return the number 3 because:

1. 10 is a neighbor of 6
2. 6 is a neighbor of 7
3. 7 is a neighbor of 3

Eventually return 3

Second example:
Matrix:

- 1 2 3
- 4 5 6
- 7 8 9

The user entered the code: 7,8,6,3

The algorithm should return 2 because:

1. 7 is a neighbor of 8
2. 8 is not a neighbor of 6
3. 6 is a neighbor of 3

Eventually return 2
Ofc number of operations equal length of array - 1

[Sorry for "ile" and "tutaj", i'm polish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9IjK.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem. Can you demonstrate you actually attempted it first?

Comment: @JIguadeza I've added as a img link

Comment: Can the values in the matrix be other than just a sequence of numbers?

Comment: Nope, {1,2,3,4,5 ... rows * columns}

Answer (score 0):

If all the codes are unique, use them as keys to a dictionary (with (row/col) pairs as values). Loop thru the 2nd item in user input to the end, check if math.Abs(cur.row-prev.row)+math.Abs(cur.col-prev.col)==1. This is not space efficient but deal with user input in linear complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is you have 4 conditions, one for each direction. Given any matrix of the shape `n,m` which is made of a sequence of integers AND given any element:

1. The element left or right will always be `+ or - 1` to the given element.
2. The element up or down will always be `+ or - m` to the given element.

So, if `abs(x-y) is 1 or m`, then x and y are neighbors.

I demonstrate this in python.

```
def get_neighbors(seq,matrix):
    
    #Conditions
    check = lambda x,y,m: np.abs(x-y)==1 or np.abs(x-y)==m
    
    #Pairs of sequences appended with m
    params = zip(seq, seq[1:], [matrix.shape[1]]*(len(seq)-1))
    
    neighbours = [check(*i) for i in params]
    count = sum(neighbours)
    return neighbours, count

seq = [7,8,6,3]
matrix = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))
neighbours, count = get_neighbors(seq, matrix)

print('Matrix:')
print(matrix)
print('')
print('Sequence:', seq)
print('')
print('Count of neighbors:',count)
```

```
Matrix:
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]]

Sequence: [10, 6, 7, 3]

Count of neighbors: 3
```

Another example -

```
seq = [7,8,6,3]
matrix = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))
neighbours, count = get_neighbors(seq, matrix)
```

```
Matrix:
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

Sequence: [7, 8, 6, 3]

Count of neighbors: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

So your input is the width of a table, the height of a table, and a list of numbers.

```
W = 4, H = 3, list = [10,6,7,3]
```

There are two steps:

1. Convert the list of numbers into a list of row/column coordinates (1 to [1,1], 5 to [2,1], 12 to [3,4]).
2. In the new list of coordinates, find consequent pairs, which have one coordinate identical, and the other one has a difference of 1.

Both steps are quite simple ("for" loops). Do you have problems with 1 or 2?

Comment: Maybe with first for loop

Comment: So there are 4 values in each row. Numbers 1,2,3,4 are in the first row, 5,6,7,8 in the second, etc.

So just divide the coordinate by 4 to get the row index. E.g. 10/4 = 2.5, "two and a half rows", so it must be in a third row.